# Выборка строк таблицы как столбцов

Tags: sql-server

У меня возникла следующая проблема.
Есть таблица такого вида:

```
name org  date       value
A    o1   2018-01-01 1
B    o2   2018-01-01 2
C    o3   2018-01-01 3
```

Мне нужно выбрать из нее данные в формате:

```
name o1 o2 o3
A    1
B        2
C           3
```

Есть ли какие-то способы это сделать? Список name и org может меняться в зависимости от переданных параметров.
UPD: по всей видимости, нужен PIVOT, но остается вопрос с тем, что набор org не фиксированный

Comment: К сожалению в SQL набор возможных столбцов должен быть описан заранее. Так что единственный путь, это сначала получить какие вообще значения org бывают и на основе этого динамически построить запрос, в котором в pivot они будут перечислены. И лучше бы это делать не средствами SQL а на внешнем языке, который эти данные отображает во вне

Comment: @Mike а есть ли возможность это сделать без PIVOT? после экспериментов выяснилось, что у заказчика версия ms sql, которая не умеет в него (pivot добавлен в 2008, в наличии 2005)

Comment: `select name, sum(case org when 'o1' then value end) o1, sum(case org when 'o2' then value end) o2, ... from tab group by name`

Comment: @StacyK, если что, в 2005 pivot уже был (перепроверил сейчас специально)

Comment: @Mike спасибо, попробуем

Comment: @i-one у нас ругается, что уровень совместимости не тот. не могли бы Вы подсказать, какой он должен быть?

Comment: @StacyK, _"ругается, что уровень совместимости не тот"_ хмм, значит уровень совместимости меньше 90 (80 - совместимость с SqlServer 2000, либо 70 - совместимость с SqlServer 7.0). Синтаксис pivot воспринимается с уровеня 90. Однако менять его на уже спроектированной БД только ради возможности использовать pivot не рекомендовал бы (т.к. после смены уровня совместимости желательно проводить всестороннее тестирование).